# Parse.com NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 in cellular not in wifi

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsurlconnection

I have an app that work with the parse.com backend. 
Since today have a NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 with parse.com only using cellular network. Wifi is working pretty good. What could be the issue ?

Here the full error :

```
    [Error]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003  
    "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." 
    UserInfo=0x1700f2200{NSUnderlyingError=0x170245880 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.",
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, 
    NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, 
    _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, 
    _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, 
    NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could 
    not be    found.} 
    (Code: 100, Version: 1.6.1)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you check if https://api.parse.com/ is reachable by sending a NSURLRequest from your app via your cellular network? You should receive a 404 error response, but the important part is whether the connection goes through or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that restarting my phone solve the problem.

Comment: Thank YOU.. sometimes the easiest solution is the hardest to discover. I wasted a long time trying to figure this one out. Wow, hard to believe sometimes the internal stress we create while chasing bugs ;)

Many many thanks..

Comment: worked for me! Anyone able to figure out the cause? Would hate for this to happen to a user!

Comment: This isn't really a solution. I get this all the time now.